# grunt-express need a proxy for an api to avoid cross domain issue

Tags: node.js, express, gruntjs

I'm using grunt-express and need to know how to integrate a proxy for my api calls.

I see there are various packages that can be used to proxy api calls but i cannot find an example on how to integrate it when using grunt-express.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a question in your post. Can you clarify?

Comment: How to get grunt-express to use a proxy to allow cross domain api calls ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by using grunt-json-proxy

Comment: Can you please share how you managed to get this working using json-proxy?